# Adding Multiple Wheres to a Generic Repository Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like your help on an issue.

i am using generic repository on project
here i am using method as all records

there is something i want to do
The project has 20 close input areas.
i want to create query with non-null value here

Can I include a string or other type of value that I sent in the form of a list, like the method below, into the query as where?

can you please help me ?

```cs
public List<T> allRecord(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Filter = null, int NumberofSkippedRecords = 0, int NumberofRecords = int.MaxValue, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> Arrangement = null, IList<string> Scope = null)
{
    using (var _context = new Context())
    {
        var Query = Filter == null ? _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable() : _context.Set<T>().Where(Filter).AsQueryable();

        if (Scope != null)
        {
            foreach (var Value in Scope)
            {
                Query = Query.Include(Value);
            }
        }
        if (Arrangement != null)
        {
            Query = Arrangement(Query).AsQueryable();
        }
        Query = NumberofSkippedRecords == 0 ? Query.Take(NumberofRecords) : Query.Skip(NumberofSkippedRecords).Take(NumberofRecords);

        return Query.ToList();
    }
}
```

I wanted to create a generic repository pattern but I couldn't

Comment: You don't need a generic "repository" over EF Core, a DbSet is already a generic single-entity repository, a DbContext is already a multi-entity repository *and* Unit-of-Work, and all LINQ operators are generic already. You can already write `query=query.Where(someCondition)` with EF Core and LINQ without any extra code

Comment: This adds no value over querying the DbSets directly using LINQ, giving you all the flexibility needed.

Comment: ...where do all these _generic repository over DbContext_ questions keep coming from? Some evil sinister force is miseducating new .NET Entity Framework users, yet it eludes us all. We need to shut it down and reclaim unnecessary abstractions and pointless busywork from them so we can get back to wasting time fighting broken NuGet package restores.

Comment: It's not clear how a list of arbitrary values should be converted into a `Where()`. It would help to show an example.

Comment: `.allRecord(entity => entity.Id == 0 && entity.Name == name)` - call your method this way. | Probably your question is as follows: how to compose an Expression on the fly, having the property names as strings?

Comment: Any response?..

Answer (score -1):

I will say a couple of things up front:

1. I don't like EF for REST development.  The Unit of Work pattern in it does me more harm that help.  I have plenty of examples, but I won't go there.
2. I agree that EF's DB context is a repository in itself and you should not need, for the most part a repository pattern on top.

I do, however, support the idea of a repository on top if you want to abstract away the presence of EF, or if you are doing DDD and want to create tailored repository methods that directly relate to the business needs.

So having said that, you could apply the concept of **[Model Features](https://webjose.hashnode.dev/use-model-features-to-speed-up-backend-development-in-a-dry-manner)** to be able to create generic repositories.  *Model Features* is my own creation.  Feel free to drop questions in the comments here or at the blog page.

Comment: I skimmed over your _Model Features_ article and to me it looks just the same as any other generic-repository implementation. I don't see what value it adds over `DbSet<T>` with extension-methods.

Comment: Basically, by defining features, you can add `where` conditions on the generic types, revealing model properties.  By revealing model properties, you can write generic `Where` LINQ queries because you can actually access the property in the base generic class.  Skim over a bit deeper.

Comment: Right, but we can already do that today with extension methods, with `where` constraints, over `IQueryable<T>` .

Comment: Yes, but only for the EF ORM.  Model Features can be used with any ORM.  I am not married to EF.

Comment: I have yet to come across a cogent argument in favour of abstracting over ORMs... (just because _you can_, doesn't necessarily mean _you should_).

Comment: Keep looking, don't give up.

Comment: How do you propose abstracting over an ORM that uses the Active Record paradigm vs. a mapper-based ORM? Or one that supports async IO and one that doesn't?

Comment: Before starting a lengthy discussion here, this doesn't answer the question. Please focus on what's asked. The repository pattern is not the point.